# Reload Fragment on tab change - Android

Tags: android, pagerslidingtabstrip

Ok, so the scenario is something like this. When the ChildFragments are loaded for the first time, i can easily call my `customMethod()` inside `onCreate()` or `onCreateView()`. However, what i want is that when i change the tab, i want to recall my ChildFragment's `customMethod()`
How can i achieve this?

**ParentFragment**

```
 private void initViewPagerAndTabs() {
        mMinHeaderHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.flexible_space_image_height_search_dynamic);
        mHeaderHeight = getResources().getDimensionPixelSize(R.dimen.header_height);
        mMinHeaderTranslation = -mMinHeaderHeight + getActionBarHeight();

        mHeaderLogo = (SelectableRoundedImageView) searchFragmntInflater.findViewById(R.id.header_logo);


        mPagerSlidingTabStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) searchFragmntInflater.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) searchFragmntInflater.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(1);

        mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        mPagerAdapter.setTabHolderScrollingContent(this);

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(mViewPager);
        mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setOnPageChangeListener(this);


        mHeader = searchFragmntInflater.findViewById(R.id.header);

        mActionBarTitleColor = getResources().getColor(R.color.quinto);
        mAlphaForegroundColorSpan = new AlphaForegroundColorSpan(0xffffffff);
        mSpannableString = new SpannableString(getString(R.string.app_name));
        mAlphaForegroundColorSpan = new AlphaForegroundColorSpan(mActionBarTitleColor);
        mPagerSlidingTabStrip = (PagerSlidingTabStrip) searchFragmntInflater.findViewById(R.id.tabs);

        mViewPager = (ViewPager) searchFragmntInflater.findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(4);

        mPagerAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());
        mPagerAdapter.setTabHolderScrollingContent(this);

        mViewPager.setAdapter(mPagerAdapter);

        mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setViewPager(mViewPager);
        mPagerSlidingTabStrip.setOnPageChangeListener(this);


    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        // nothing

    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
        // nothing


    }

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int position) {
        SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder> scrollTabHolders = mPagerAdapter.getScrollTabHolders();
        ScrollTabHolder currentHolder = scrollTabHolders.valueAt(position);

        currentHolder.adjustScroll((int) (mHeader.getHeight() + ViewHelper.getTranslationY(mHeader)));

    }

    @Override
    public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem, int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount, int pagePosition) {
        if (mViewPager.getCurrentItem() == pagePosition) {
            int scrollY = getScrollY(view);
            ViewHelper.setTranslationY(mHeader, Math.max(-scrollY, mMinHeaderTranslation));
            float ratio = clamp(ViewHelper.getTranslationY(mHeader) / mMinHeaderTranslation, 0.0f, 1.0f);

            // interpolate(mHeaderLogo, getActionBarIconView(), sSmoothInterpolator.getInterpolation(ratio));
            //setTitleAlpha(clamp(5.0F * ratio - 4.0F, 0.0F, 1.0F));
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void adjustScroll(int scrollHeight) {
        // nothing
    }

    public int getScrollY(AbsListView view) {
        View c = view.getChildAt(0);
        if (c == null) {
            return 0;
        }

        int firstVisiblePosition = view.getFirstVisiblePosition();
        int top = c.getTop();

        int headerHeight = 0;
        if (firstVisiblePosition >= 1) {
            headerHeight = mHeaderHeight;
        }

        return -top + firstVisiblePosition * c.getHeight() + headerHeight;
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    public int getActionBarHeight() {
        if (mActionBarHeight != 0) {
            return mActionBarHeight;
        }

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT > Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(android.R.attr.actionBarSize, mTypedValue, true);
        } else {
            getActivity().getTheme().resolveAttribute(R.attr.actionBarSize, mTypedValue, true);
        }

        mActionBarHeight = TypedValue.complexToDimensionPixelSize(mTypedValue.data, getResources().getDisplayMetrics());

        return mActionBarHeight;
    }


    @TargetApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB)
    private ImageView getActionBarIconView() {

        if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
            return (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(android.R.id.home);
        }

        return (ImageView) getActivity().findViewById(android.support.v7.appcompat.R.id.home);
    }


public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final String[] TITLES = {"ChildFragment1", "ChildFragment2", "ChildFragment3"};
    private SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder> mScrollTabHolders;
    private ScrollTabHolder mListener;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
        mScrollTabHolders = new SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder>();
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemPosition(Object object) {
        // POSITION_NONE makes it possible to reload the PagerAdapter
        return POSITION_NONE;
    }

    public void setTabHolderScrollingContent(ScrollTabHolder listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return TITLES[position];
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return TITLES.length;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {

        if (position == 0) {
            fragment = (ScrollTabHolderFragment) ChildFragment1.newInstance(position, "");
        } else if (position == 1) {
            fragment = (ScrollTabHolderFragment) ChildFragment2.newInstance(position, "");
        } else {
            fragment = (ScrollTabHolderFragment) ChildFragment3.newInstance(position, "");
        }
        mScrollTabHolders.put(position, fragment);
        if (mListener != null) {
            fragment.setScrollTabHolder(mListener);
        }

        return fragment;
    }

    public SparseArrayCompat<ScrollTabHolder> getScrollTabHolders() {
        return mScrollTabHolders;
    }

}
```

**Child Fragment**

```
   public static ChildFragment1 newInstance(int position, String query) {
            ChildFragment1 f = new ChildFragment1();
            Bundle b = new Bundle();
            b.putInt(ARG_POSITION, position);


            f.setArguments(b);
            return f;
        }
     @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        mPosition = getArguments().getInt(ARG_POSITION);


    }
    customMethod(){
    //This method returns an arraylist data

}
```

Comment: Please clarify your question

Comment: @Gatunox please check my edited question.

Comment: why don't you make your method static? if you do, there will be only one copy of that method for all instances of your class ChildFragment1

Comment: @Gatunox yea, but then i'll also need to make the variables inside it as static. You see, there an asynchronous retrofit call that i make inside it and i also set the views with the data obtained from that aync call. 
Do you still think i should go for the static custom method?

Comment: if you want to "recall" your ChildFragment's customMethod(), there is only 3 ways i can think of. I don't know exactly why you need this approach, i think something is wrong with you design though. but putting my thoughts aside. 1-Make your method static. 2-Save the returned set of data as a member variable in the parent fragment. 3-store the data at application level in a sigleton class, so when you request an instance of the class you will always point to the exiting instance. Basically, you will have to choose depending of your design and functionality. Regards.

Comment: @Gatunox wow ! Really, a meaningful answer. I'l get back to this post and post a solution to this question of mine. Thank you, i appreciate your help. And thanks for pointing out regarding my approach.. :)

Answer (score 0):

So, i followed Gatunox's suggestion and made my custom method as static. So now, i'm able to refresh my fragment data by calling my custom method directly from the newinstance() method.